# Running gitlab repository on a dataset

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am developing a python code and am hosting it in my personal gitlab instance. This code runs on a dataset of yaml files and produces some outputs. Now I want to use runners to test my code on a test dataset, and then if it passed, run it on the main dataset and have the results.

How is this possible?

Comment: The question is rather generic, you should add in more details. The general idea should be to use a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to run a python script which tests the code on a sample dataset in one stage. Then, the next stage of the CI will run the code on the whole dataset. If you put in more details (like how is the dataset stored, the `.gitlab-ci.yml` you tried to write etc) we could help you more.

Comment: My problem at this point is exactly where to store the test and real datasets. Should I put them in the repository itself? or somewhere else. If I put them somewhere else, how should I get it in the runner?

Sorry If I'm asking obvious questions. I'm quiet new with gitlab and find its documentation hard to follow.

Comment: Your setup seems kind of strange. Usually the CI is used only to build the application (that is, compile, test and package): in this phase, you should run your test dataset and see if the results match what you expect. The output of the build is the tested application, that usually is deployed and used (in your case, runned against the real dataset). Am I missing something about what you want to achieve?